# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If $a_1=2$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-a_n+1$ for $n\geqslant1$ then how do I find  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}.$$
Any hint is enough.
Thanks.

Comment: oh yeah sorry..ill edit it

Comment: You mean you need to find $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}...$$

Comment: yup its 2..ive mentioned it in the first line

Comment: Write $a_{n+1} - 1 = a_n(a_n-1)$. Take the inverse of this and deduce $\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{a_n - 1} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}$.

Comment: Hint: [Sylvester's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_sequence). in particular, the relation $\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{a_n-1} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}$ which turn your sum to a telescoping one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $a_{n+1}-1=a_n^2-a_n$ and
$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}=\frac{1}{a_n^2-a_n}=\frac{1}{a_n(a_n-1)}=\frac{1}{a_n-1}-\frac{1}{a_n}\implies \frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{1}{a_n-1}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}.$$
Hence, the sum is telescoping:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{a_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{a_n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{a_n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{a_{n}-1}=\frac{1}{a_1-1}-\frac{1}{a_{N+1}-1}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes i definitely can take it from here! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k} = 1-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}.$$

See if you can prove this by induction.

Note: I found this identity by listing the first few partial sums.

Comment: Yes thank you! But could you please provide a method that doesn't involve induction

Comment: @Winther The way I came up with it was listing the few partial sums. It's not too hard to figure out how to represent them. Robert Z's answer provides the telescoping series.